# set a header row value even when no records/result in mysql query (both CASE and WHERE clausules)

Tags: mysql

I've been searching and couldn't find any post like the problem I have:

I need to set an specific value in a "header", but since there's no record, I can't make it possible.

```
create table Det_TMZF_Authorizations 
(id int, id_Det_TMZF int, authorization_format varchar(1));

Insert into Det_TMZF_Authorizations (id, id_Det_TMZF, authorization_format) values (1,1,'E');
Insert into Det_TMZF_Authorizations (id, id_Det_TMZF, authorization_format) values (2,2,'M');
```

```
SELECT 
     CASE   dda.Authorization_Format
       WHEN COALESCE(sum(dda.Authorization_Format), '0') THEN 'N'   
       ELSE 'Y'
     END                        declare_certificate,
    -- 'Y'                          declare_certificate,
        dda.Authorization_Format    authorization_format
FROM    Det_TMZF_Authorizations dda
WHERE   dda.id_Det_TMZF = 3
```

(Edit: tables with data and expected)

If I ask for id_Det_TMZF = 1 or 2, I have no problem setting "declare_certificate" = 'Y'.

| declare_certificate | id_Det_TMZF | authorization_format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | 1 | E |
| Y | 2 | M |

but I need to set declare_certificate = 'N' when there's no record.
I already tried "IFNULL(dda.Authorization_Format), '0') THEN 'N'" but got more errors than results.

I want this result:

| declare_certificate | id_Det_TMZF | authorization_format |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N | NULL | NULL |

Comment: Please provide some formatted tablular data and your actual expected results

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL? It will be much easier in the application language, which can check if the query returns anything.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! I thought it could be more organized if I did it on the database side. but trying it on the app side took me less time than the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `UNION` operation plus an aggregation with a little trick to solve this problem:

```
SELECT 
     case when max(a.authorization_format) = '0' then 'N' else 'Y' end declare_certificate
from (
  SELECT dda.authorization_format
  FROM    Det_TMZF_Authorizations dda
  WHERE   dda.id_Det_TMZF = 3
  UNION all
  SELECT '0'
) a;
```

The trick is to rely on the ASCII table ordering. Since `[0-9]` are always smaller in the ASCII table the `max` operation will always get the rows with an ALPHA char on it. The query will always returns two rows one with the result of the original query and one from the `Union` operation, then we apply the aggregation which will take advantage of the ASCII ordering. If the original query has no rows on it, it will process the row from the `UNION`.

See it working in here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/teQhRGvnSh4vc1jAevRT8v/1

Comment: I've edited original as I inverted the condition.

Answer (score 1):

A `LEFT JOIN` to a single (dummy) row will ensure the result set to have at least one row.

```
select 
  case when dda.id is not null
    then 'Y'
    else 'N'
  end as declare_certificate,
  dda.id_Det_TMZF, 
  dda.authorization_format
from (select 1) as dummy
left join Det_TMZF_Authorizations dda 
  on dda.id_Det_TMZF = 3
```

Your conditions must be in the `ON` clause in this case. If there are no rows matching the conditions, all rows from the right table (including primary key) will be `NULL`. Check the PK for `NULL` and you will know if the result has any rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

@Jorge Campos' answer worked for me, but I as someone suggested in the comments, it was better to try do it in the application language. That's how I made it possible. Anyways, thank you everyone!